# custom search for options relevant for a particular item that is selected django

Tags: python, django

Am having a search box, that i can use to search for items in django database and prints the results out at the template as a table.

Presently the code is working but i intend customizing the search, to accommodate a select tag so that whatever the user typed and and selected should query the database and fetch the outcome or result.

i tried but it not working

here is my code:

```
def search_form(request):

    data = OrderItem.objects.order_by().values_list('certification_type', flat=True).distinct()
    print data

    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']

        print q

        x = request.GET['certification_type']
        print x

        items = OrderItem.objects.filter(Q(order_type__iexact=x and order_type__iexact=q) | Q(certification_type__iexact=x and certification_type__iexact=q) | Q(item__iexact=x and item__iexact=q)
         | Q(certification_no__iexact=x and certification_no__iexact=q) | Q(client__user__email__iexact=x and client__user__email__iexact=q) | Q(client__phone_number__iexact=x and client__phone_number__iexact=q)
         | Q(created_on__icontains=x and created_on__icontains=q))




        for x in items:
            for q in items:
                print items


        return render(request, 'i/search_results.html', {'items':items, 'query':q})
    else:
        return render(request, 'i/search_form.html', {'error':True,  "data":data})
```

Comment: why `for q and x in items`?

Comment: the condition for q and x in items:  is the problem but i don't know how to figure it out

Comment: it makes no sense to me. If you want to add filtering for x, then add some conditions in the filter arguments. Then to test just `print items`